# Why service activator has got access only to payload and not headers etc

Tags: spring-integration

Why it is like that service activator has got access only to payload while message transformer has got access to payload and request header....

Regards,
Lalit

Comment: Please, be more specific and share the config on the matter to discuss. In general: it does. @Headers annotation, Message<?> as POJO method argument, headers as SpEL variable etc.